# SQL REPLACE function inside Xml.modify 'replace value of'

Tags: sql-server, xml, xpath

I'm trying to update some XML data in SQL Server. The XML contains data that looks like this:

```
<root>
    <id>1</id>
    <timestamp>16-10-2017 19:24:55</timestamp>
</root>
```

Let's say this XML exists in a column called `Data` in a table called `TestTable`.
I would like to be able to change the hyphens in the timestamp to forward slashes.

I was hoping I might be able to do something like:

```
update TestTable
set Data.modify('replace value of 
(/root/timestamp/text())[1] with REPLACE((/root/timestamp/text())[1], "-", "/")')
```

I get the following error:

> XQuery [TestTable]: There is no function '{http://www.w3.org/2004/07/xpath-functions}:REPLACE()'

When I think about it, this makes sense. But I wonder, is there a way to do this in a single update statement? Or do I first need to query the timestamp value and save it as a variable, and then update the XML with the variable?

Comment: Is your Data column of type XML or Varchar?

Comment: @DhruvJoshi - XML

Comment: What is the namespace?

Comment: The correct answer very much depends on what you need it for. The task' context would be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>Note: this answer assumes you want to have this formatted for the purpose of displaying this as a string, and not parsing the content as a xs:dateTime. If you want the latter, Shungo's answer will format it as such.</sub>

---

It seems that [`replace`](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath-functions-31/#func-replace) is not a [supported XQuery function in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/xquery-functions-against-the-xml-data-type) at the time of this writing. You can use the [`substring`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/functions-on-string-values-substring) function along with the [`concat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/xquery/functions-on-string-values-concat) function in a ["replace value of (XML DML)"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/xml/replace-value-of-xml-dml) though.

```sql
CREATE TABLE #t(x XML);
INSERT INTO #t(x)VALUES(N'<root><id>1</id><timestamp>16-10-2017 19:24:55</timestamp></root>');

UPDATE
    #t
SET
    x.modify('replace value of (/root/timestamp/text())[1]
              with concat(substring((/root/timestamp/text())[1],1,2),
                          "/",
                          substring((/root/timestamp/text())[1],4,2),
                          "/",
                          substring((/root/timestamp/text())[1],7)
                         ) ') 

SELECT*FROM #t;
```

Giving as a result:

```
<root><id>1</id><timestamp>16/10/2017 19:24:55</timestamp></root>
```

Comment: @Shnugo I tested it, it does work. I could not come up with anything better than this though. It would have been great if replace was supported.

Comment: No, it's not the approach itself, but the suggestion to fiddle around with inappropriate dateTime-formats...

Comment: @Shnugo Oh I see your answer now. Agreed, ISO timestamp is the way to go, but I didn't get from the OP's question that he wanted a ISO timestamp, rather a display string. So I answered in that vein.

Answer (score 4):

You can also do this with a join to an inline view and use the SQL REPLACE function:

```
   CREATE TABLE TestTable
   (    
       Id INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
       Data XML NOT NULL
   )

   INSERT TestTable (Data) VALUES ('<root>
        <id>1</id>
        <timestamp>16-10-2017 19:24:55</timestamp>
    </root>')

    UPDATE TestTable
    SET Data.modify('replace value of 
    (/root/timestamp/text())[1] with sql:column("T2.NewData")')
    FROM TestTable T1
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT Id
        , REPLACE( Data.value('(/root/timestamp/text())[1]', 'nvarchar(max)'), '-', '/') AS NewData
        FROM TestTable
    ) T2
    ON T1.Id = T2.Id

    SELECT * FROM TestTable
```

Answer (score 1):

If there's no **external need you have to fullfill**, you should use ISO8601 date/time strings within XML.

Your dateTime-string is culture related. Reading this on different systems with differing language or dateformat settings will lead to errors or - **even worse!!!** - to wrong results.

A date like "08-10-2017" can be the 8th of October or the 10th of August...

The worst point is, that this might pass all your tests successfully, but will break on a customer's machine with strange error messages or bad results down to real data dammage!

Switching the hyphens to slashes is just cosmetic! An XML is a **strictly defined data container**. Any non-string data must be represented as a secure convertible string.

This is what you should do:

```
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY,YourXML XML);
INSERT INTO @tbl VALUES
(N'<root>
    <id>1</id>
    <timestamp>16-10-2017 19:24:55</timestamp>
</root>');

UPDATE @tbl SET YourXml.modify(N'replace value of (/root/timestamp/text())[1] 
                                 with concat(  substring((/root/timestamp/text())[1],7,4), "-"
                                              ,substring((/root/timestamp/text())[1],4,2), "-"
                                              ,substring((/root/timestamp/text())[1],1,2), "T"
                                              ,substring((/root/timestamp/text())[1],12,8)
                                            ) cast as xs:dateTime?');

SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

The result

```
<root>
  <id>1</id>
  <timestamp>2017-10-16T19:24:55</timestamp>
</root>
```

Comment: My specific use case is that the entire chunk of xml is deserialised in c#, not manipulated in the database. In the C# object the timestamp property is actually a string. This string is then parsed with DateTime.ParseExact(...). My problem is that the data can sometimes be written in a different region to which it is read. We have the culture loaded based on the location of the logged in user. I think ideally I would store this as UTC, but I have to deal with what is already implemented. Hence i need to modify some data that already exists.

Comment: I'm grateful that you took the time to respond. I appreciate that you don't have to help strangers on the internet, however your response comes across as awfully condescending. I don't think this contributes positively to this kind of forum.

Comment: @MikeB Sorry, I did not want to be impolite by any means... I just wanted to point out, that this is not a matter of taste, but a (potentially) critical approach. For now this is handled within C# with `ParseExact`, but one day some will use this date within a SQL Query like `DELETE FROM YourTable WHERE LastModify<YourDate` Now read `01-12-2017` as the 12th of January and almost a year of data is gone... Just to get this clear: Whatever you have outside - within XML you should use ISO8601. You never know who will use this in future and how...

Comment: @MikeB I edited my answer to take the *awfully condescending* away (had to google that word first :-)  )

Comment: @MikeB Shnugo is by no means condescending :-), he's just defending a valid position. He is coming from the perspective of the data being parsed as `xs:dateTime`. It is likely better to have date/time data formatted the ISO way... for portability's sake.

Comment: @TT. - I totally get the point being made, and i agree with its validity. It's all good. I just wanted to raise the point that the response in its original form carried with it an additional sentiment, which I do not believe was intended, but changed the ambient of the forum. Shnugo responded kindly. I'm grateful to both of you for the time you've taken to help with this issue

Answer (score 0):

you can try string replacement like below

```
update testtable 
set data= cast(
concat(
    left(cast(data as varchar(max)),charindex('<timestamp>',cast(data as varchar(max)))+len('<timestamp>')-1),
    replace(
        substring(
                    cast(data as varchar(max)),
                    len('<timestamp>')   + 
                        charindex( '<timestamp>', cast(data as varchar(max))) ,
                    charindex('</timestamp>',cast(data as varchar(max)))
                        -charindex('<timestamp>',cast(data as varchar(max)))
                        -len('<timestamp>')
                 ),
        '-','/'),
    right(cast(data as varchar(max)),len(cast(data as varchar(max)))-charindex('</timestamp>',cast(data as varchar(max)))+1)
       ) as xml)

select * 
from testtable
```

<kbd>**[working demo](http://rextester.com/ZOI31721)**</kbd>

Comment: This might work, but is not a good suggestion. Even worse the manipulation of an XML should not be done on string level. This can have various side effects...